# Spring Boot Social disable ConnectController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-social

I'm using Spring Boot Social for OAuth authentication via `SpringSocialConfigurer` and all OAuth authentication with 3rd party OAuth providers goes through `/auth/providerId` path.

Everything works fine but I noticed that `ConnectController` is also presented and configured in my application:

```
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[error],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2ErrorCallback(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.removeConnections(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatus(org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatus(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[oauth_token],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth1Callback(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET],params=[code],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2Callback(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
2015-05-02 12:02:47 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}/{providerUserId}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.removeConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
```

I think I don't need `ConnectController`. Is any way to disable it ?

**UPDATED:**

This is my current **SocialConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SocialUserService socialUserService;

    @Autowired
    private TextEncryptor textEncryptor;

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        Neo4jUsersConnectionRepository connectionRepository = new Neo4jUsersConnectionRepository(userService, socialUserService,
                (SocialAuthenticationServiceLocator) connectionFactoryLocator, textEncryptor);
        connectionRepository.setConnectionSignUp(new UserConnectionSignUp(userService));
        return connectionRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService() {
        return new DBSocialUserDetailService(userService);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be simply able to remove the `ConnectionController` bean from your Social context configuration.

Comment: In a what way ? I don't declare this bean manually ?

Comment: You need to have a separate Social context for your configuration. If Spring Boot does it automatically for you then you have to still make your own where you define what you exactly need. You cannot exclude anything. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/blob/77a79c2fcba8102463acbe84457614f89d0648a4/spring-social-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/showcase/config/SocialConfig.java

Comment: Can I simple override 
 public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository)  and return null from this method in my own SocialConfig ?

Comment: I have added my current SocialConfig into the question body

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't help. You need to disable auto configuration for Spring Social and add your provider specific configuration into the `SocialConfig`, then the bean won't be created. `SocialWebAutoConfiguration` class is what you would need to exclude from your auto configuration by doing `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= ..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SocialWebAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Resolved to me.

**UPDATE**

I needed to create the following class to work correctly.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.social.UserIdSource;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.ConnectionFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableSocial;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurer;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class MySocialConfig  implements SocialConfigurer {
    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //
    // SocialConfigurer implementation methods
    //

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                if (authentication == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
                }
                return authentication.getName();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Its don't work for me. @SpringBootApplication(exclude={SocialWebAutoConfiguration.class, FacebookAutoConfiguration.class})